# Context is not a member of MyProg._Default

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am endeavouring to correct a problem with a Web Project:-

> Could not load type 'MyProg._Default'.

To fix this I have adopted the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394003/could-not-load-type-site-default) and changed `CodeBehind` into `CodeFile`. As is customary in ASP.Net Whack-a-Mole, this has introduced a new and different error:-

> Context is not a member of 'MyProg._Default'

The very strange solution to this suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798534/context-is-not-a-member-of-in-asp-net-usercontrol) doesn't seem likely to fix the problem as I have no user-defined controls on the form.

I have two questions, really. First, is changing `CodeBehind` this way likely to fix the original problem, and if so how do I fix the new problem?

**Edit** to answer wazz's question, the top line in the aspx is:-

```
<%@ Language="VB"
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    Inherits="MyProg._Default" 
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"
    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

and the class is defined thus:-

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: just a couple simple checks (i use lower case): page: `AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_default"` and .cs : `public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page`. anything different for you?

Comment: i imagine you've already seen more than a few threads but here's another jic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707835/could-not-load-type-webapp1-default-in-asp-net

Comment: @wazz, Thanks for the suggestion; I've answered your questions in the edit.

Comment: i'm used to websites and i don't know if projects are any different, but have you tried removing the `MyProg.` part from MyProg._Default ? sry if i'm missing the core, it just seems it should be inheriting the same name.